# How to search in table with fulltext search same as google?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, t-sql

I am working on pretty enterprise document management system (DMS project) for big company.

DMS database is Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and document table name is "Document".

At this time more than 4,000,000 records are available in document table.

I need to search in document table same as Google search through SQL Server Full-text Search with very good performance(less than 1 second response time).

User see single text box for intelligence search. For example user need to find document that code contain "1107" and author name contains "Albert", therefore in that text box types: *1107 Albert*

I generated below query to find this:

```
select count(*) over() totalRowFound, DocumentID 
from dbo.Document 
where contains(*,N'("*1107*")) AND contains(*,N'("*Albert*"))
```

I used * in contains function for better search result but response time is about 4~7 second.

I know google algorithm is very complicated but I want to implement intelligence search like Google concept in only 4~10 million record with less than 1 second response time.

How can I improve this query? 
or 
What is best practice for intelligence search same as google?

Answer (score 1):

With the * you are searching all columns
Try

```
where contains(code,N'("*1107*"))
```

How is searching all columns better search results if they want to search a specific column?

Not going to SQL fulltext search the same as Google as they are not the same engines.
I don't think the Google engine is available.
Lucene is a freeware search engine.

Why did you go down a path of writing your own DMS?

Comment: Is it possible to decrease overall query time by changing those search terms to simple phrases of nvarchar "1107" and "Albert", no longer looking for prefix searches?  There also seem to be an inconsistent number of single quotes in the original question.

Comment: @tommy_o Lots of options to optimize. OP is non responsive.

Answer (score 1):

When you say 'Google search', what you really mean is an [inverse index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index).  Apache's Lucene project provides this functionality in a similar indexing fashion.  SQL Server's FullText uses inverse indexing as well.

If you want very, very fast performing text searches, you might want to try using Lucene or Solr as it has some features that SQL Server Full-Text search does not (and vice-versa) and when properly configured, can perform very well.

Comment: You have it backwards. Lucene is the engine and is used by Solar and Elastic Search. Lucene is not always faster than SQL FTS.

Comment: Ya, you're right.  I eliminated a bunch.  Either product, when poorly utilized, will perform horribly.